# How to slice all of the elements of pandas dataframe at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have the following data stored in my Pandas datframe:

```
           Factor          SimTime          RealTime  SimStatus
0    Factor[0.48]   SimTime[83.01]  RealTime[166.95]  Paused[F]
1    Factor[0.48]   SimTime[83.11]  RealTime[167.15]  Paused[F]
2    Factor[0.49]   SimTime[83.21]  RealTime[167.36]  Paused[F]
3    Factor[0.48]   SimTime[83.31]  RealTime[167.57]  Paused[F]
```

I want to create a new dataframe with only everything within [].

I am attempting to use the following code:

`df = dataframe.apply(lambda x: x.str.slice(start=x.str.find('[')+1, stop=x.str.find(']')))`

However, all I see in `df` is NaN. Why? What's going on? What should I do to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: If anyone solves it, please tell me why this approach is wrong and how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @abhilb provided a resolution. Check below.

Comment: That's okay, but I want to know what is wrong with this approach, I just don't want to ignore this problem by looking at another way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: You are right about that, however, this was just a tool for me to extract a data, so I am fine with the resolution for the time being.  Nevertheless, I will keep an eye here if someone sees it and points out any mistake here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to replace the contents.

```py
df.replace(r'\w+\[([\S]+)\]', r'\1', regex=True)
```

**Edit**

*replace* function of pandas `DataFrame`

`Replace values given in to_replace with value`

The target string and the value with which it needs to be replaced can be regex expressions. And for that you need to set the `regex=True` in the arguments to `replace`

https://regex101.com/r/7KCs6q/1
Look at the above link to see the explanation of the regular expression in detail.

Basically it is using the non whitespace content within the square brackets as the value and any string with some characters followed by square brackets with non whitespace characters as the target string.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Can you please explain, what just happened?

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation. I will read more about regex.